# Excel data extraction using regular expressions through Python

Tags: python, mysql, excel, ms-access

This is part 1 of a series of questions I will make on this forum so bear with me on this one. I am a novice programmer who took on a large project because i like to torture myself, so please be kind.

I am writing a Python script to process an Excel document full of accounts (See example below), each one being the same format, extract specific type of data from it, and then export that data to a SQL table. This is the process flow I have in mind when illustrating the script on paper:

The input is a large Excel document containing bookkeeping accounts with this format below:

[Account format example and the data to be extracted highlighted, I believe the software used to produce this is an antiquated accounting software named "Zeus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htdze.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htdze.png)

The data to be extracted is the account name and number (they're on the same cell so I find it easier to extract them altogether so that I can use them as a primary key in a SQL table; will talk about that on another post) and the whole table of details of the account as highlighted above. Mind you, there are thousands of bookkeeping accounts of this format on the document and multiple of these are used for the same account name and number, meaning they have the same header, but different details.

The data processing will go like this:

1. Use regular expressions to match, extract, and store in an array, each account name and number (so that I can keep record of every account number and use them as a primary key in a SQL table)
2. Extract and match the content of each account details table to their respective account name and number (haven't figured out how to do that yet, however, I will be using a relationship table to link them to their primary key once data is exported).
3. Export the extracted data into a database software (mySQL or MS Access... will most likely use MS Access).
4. After data is extracted and processed, a Excel report is to be created consisting on a table with the name and number of the account on the first column and then the details of the account on the following columns (will post about that later on).

**Part 1**: Excel data extraction/"scraping"

Quick note: I have tried multiple methods such as (MS Access, VBA and MS Power Automate) to do this and avoid having to manually code everything, ended up failing miserably, so I decided to bite the bullet and just do it.

So here's the question: after doing some research, I came across multiple methods to extract data from an excel, and several methods to use regex to do web scraping and PDF data extraction.

Is there a way to extract data from an Excel document through Python using regex match? If so, how could I do that?

PS: I will be documenting my journey through this forum on another post in order to help other fellow data entry workers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Python script to extract data from excel sheet and input into website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333004/use-python-script-to-extract-data-from-excel-sheet-and-input-into-website)

Answer (score 0):

Look into these python modules:

```
import xlwt
from xlwt.Workbook import *
import xlsxwriter
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
```

Then you can use pandas dataframe like:

```
data = pd.read_excel('testacct.xlsx')
```

This will put the entire spreadsheet into a dict with generic column names:

[image]

If there are multiple sheets, then the df object will be a list of dicts.  Each column is a list or row data.

You can traverse the rows like:

```
cols = data.keys()
for row in range(len(data[cols[0]])):
    for col in cols:
        print(data[col][row])
    print("--")
```

You can join the column data and strip out spaces.
Then you can use regex to any of the header values.